# Grails: Is it possible to set log level for specified exception?

Tags: grails, logging

Is it possible to change `log level` for some exceptions in Grails?

I guess that `GrailsExceptionResolver` logs all exceptions as errors. Maybe there is some way to divide exception logging?

For example I have my exception. UserNotFoundException and I want to log it with level info(warn or whatever), not error.

This could look strange, I`m trying to find out is it possible or not.

I can intercept exception and handle it in separate controller, but it is required to write some code.

Comment: please provide more details about your actual issue, it's hard to guess which exception and why is not logged properly by your app

Comment: Actually it is logged, but I'm trying to figure out is it possible to change log level for particular exceptions, not all.